# Couldn't generate scaffold for file upload

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, scaffolding

I tried to generate a view for file upload but the upload part was missing and the rest class members have view generated for them

View Model

```
namespace myapps.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class UserPhotoUploadViewModel
    {

        public HttpPostedFile PhotoFile
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public Guid UserID
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }
}
```

Generated View

```
@model myapps.Models.ViewModels.UserPhotoUploadViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>UserPhotoUploadModel</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserID)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Am I expected to fill in the rest? Is this a usual behaviour and are there limit to what asp.net MVC3 could generate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is standard behavior. You can examine the default T4 Template and see how it works, it should be located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Web\MVC 3\CodeTemplates\AddView\CSHTML\Create.tt`

The most important method is `GetEligibleProperties` - as you can see it gets only primitive types (that are public and so on).

Here's an example of dealing with `HttpPostedFile` in ASP.NET MVC projects [Can EditorFor() be used to create <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113390/can-editorfor-be-used-to-create-input-type-file)