# How to upload a file in folder and save path in database?

Tags: model-view-controller, file-upload

im curently working on a registration page using mvc 5  which consist of some textboxs and a file input.i want all data to be stored using entities , MVC

I Would appreciate help on this issue Thanks

input=text --->Name,Gender,DOB,Nationality ,And 
input=file

By using first code approach Please  Thanks without razor and php Please its just simple html page

Comment: Welcome, please refer to this page to ask a good question : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Stack Overflow is not a place to ask for complete solutions, show us your code and we'll help you ;)

Comment: refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686758/couldnt-generate-scaffold-for-file-upload) or [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20446580/upload-image-included-in-mvc-model)