# MVC file uploading

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am maing my MVC application and I would like to make a nice file upload in my view. My controller is like this so far:

```
public ActionResult PickGroupForHomework(PickGroupForHomeworkViewModel model)
        {
            ClassDeclarationsDBEntities2 entities = new ClassDeclarationsDBEntities2();
            model.groups = entities.Groups.ToList();
            model.users = entities.Users.ToList();
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                model.subject_id = model.subject_id;
                model.groups = model.groups;
                model.users = model.users;
                return View(model);
            }
            return View(model);

        }
```

And in my view I would like to make a file upload so that I can retrieve it in `if(ModelState.IsValid` and then upload it as a file on server. How do I do this?
**EDIT:**
So I added this to my view:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.file, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="file" name="file" />
                    </div>
</div>
```

But how do I pass the chosen file to the `HttpPostedFileBase file` defined in model?
**EDIT2:**
My view now if like this:

```
@model ClassDeclarationsThsesis.Models.PickGroupForHomeworkViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Pick Group For Homework";
}

<h2>Setting homework</h2>

@foreach (var user in Model.users)
{
    if (user.email.Replace(" ", String.Empty) == HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)
    {
        if (user.user_type.Replace(" ", String.Empty) == 2.ToString()|| user.user_type.Replace(" ", String.Empty) == 3.ToString())
        {
            using (Html.BeginForm("PickGroupForHomework", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <hr />
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.deadline, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.deadline, new { @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.file, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <div class="editor-field">

                            @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.file, new { @class="col-md-2 control-label"})
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.file)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Submit" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                            }
                        }
                        if (user.user_type.Replace(" ", String.Empty) == 1.ToString() )
                        {
                            <p>You do not have enough permissions to enter this page. Contact the administrator.</p>
                                }

                            }
                        }
```

And apparently this `EditorFor`results in such view:
[image]

Comment: `ModelState.IsValid` returns `true` or `false`. You cannot retrieve a file from that.

Comment: Of course I cannot retrieve it from this. But if a model is valid, I can retrieve it from model probably. @Shyju

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Upload ASP.NET MVC 3.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193842/file-upload-asp-net-mvc-3-0)

Comment: There are many examples of file upload in ASP.NET MVC.  Have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Simply add a new property of type HttpPostedFileBase to your view model and have an input file field in your form. The input file element's name and your new property name should match.

Comment: @Shyju See the edit. Anyway, after submitting, the file property in model is null.

Comment: Did you add the new property with name `file` in your view model ?

Comment: @Shyju Of course, it is of type `HttpPostedFileBase`

Comment: You need to use `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.file)`. There has to be a connection between the server-side model property and the input on the client side. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6113390/215552

Comment: Can you share your view markup ? Is your input inside a form ?

Comment: @Shyju see the edit

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan See the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file upload to work from a form, the form should have
enctype attribute with value set to "multipart/form-data"

Use this code

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("PickGroupForHomework", "Account", FormMethod.Post, 
                 new {  @class = "form-horizontal",enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

This will generate the html markup for a `form` tag with `enctype` attribute value set to "multipart/form-data"