# HttpPostedFileBase in model generates three <input type="file">

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am facing a weird phenomenon which I can reproduce every time.

My model is:

```
[Display(Name = "Upload File")]
[DataType(DataType.Upload)]
public System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase file { get; set; }
```

My Razor is (I leave out the css classes):

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.file)
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.file, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "file" } })
```

The above gives:

[image]

Where did the three `<input type="file">` come from?

However, if in the model I change the type of `file` to `string` (instead of `HttpPostedFileBase`) then one `<input type="file">` shows.

How do I have a file upload control using a Html helper in the Razor page?

Comment: Is it enough to just have `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.file)`? I tried to repro and get 3 other inputs, each named `ContentLength`, `ContentType` and `FileName` while using `new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "file" } }`, but not while using `TextBoxFor` helper.

Comment: Don't use editor. If using helper then use textbox with type attribute set via helper or manual provide an input tag with necessary attributes. Editor will create input for public properties of bound model property

Comment: @Both, does `TextBoxFor` give the file control? Earlier I tried that, but it gave me a text box, despite an explicit `@type="file"`.

Comment: I created [a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NLbKVf) to show file upload with `TextBoxFor` helper, make sure the property type set to `HttpPostedFileBase` too. As I tested out, `EditorFor` tried to create inputs for several public properties inside `HttpPostedFileBase`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can EditorFor() be used to create <input type="file">?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113390/can-editorfor-be-used-to-create-input-type-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know in MVC 4, `EditorFor` helper doesn't support `htmlAttributes` yet ([this `object` parameter is available for MVC 5.1 or above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3735400/html-attributes-for-editorfor-in-asp-net-mvc)), usually the file input from `HttpPostedFileBase` property is generated by using `TextBoxFor` helper:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.file, new { type = "file" })
```

**Note:**

While trying to use `htmlAttributes` inside `EditorFor`, I found that the helper generates other 3 inputs, each named `ContentLength`, `ContentType` and `FileName`, hence I suspected the helper created inputs from several public property members of `HttpPostedFileBase` class instead of the property itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the EditorFor you will need to specify one for HttpPostedFileBase. Under Views/Shared/EditorTemplates add a file called HttpPostedFileBase.cshtml with content like this (Set Build to Content):

```
@model HttpPostedFileBase
@{
    var htmlAttributes = HtmlHelper.AnonymousObjectToHtmlAttributes(ViewData["htmlAttributes"]);
    htmlAttributes["type"] = "file";
}
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model, htmlAttributes)
```